# Footcite in Float Caption

Tags: biblatex, floats, footnotes, citing

Is there an easy workaround for using `\footcite{...}` command in figure/table captions, to produce the same citation formatting in the footer as if the citation was used outside of the float.

At the moment, the citation in the float is being skipped. In usual footnotes under such circumstance, I would use `\footnotemark{...}` and `\footnotetext{...}`, however, the alleged equivalent command, `\footcitetext{...}` does not yield the same result.

MWE Below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@book{key01,
  author = {Lastname, Firstname.},
  year = {2014},
  title = {Book Title},
}
@book{key02,
  author = {Lastname, Firstname.},
  year = {2014},
  title = {Book Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\textheight=150pt% just for the example
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \caption{A Caption including FootCite \footcite{key01}, note this citation will be omitted from footer. }
    \end{figure}
    The Standard Method (Desired Formatting)\footcite{key01}
    The Alternate Method (Incorrect Formatting)\footnotemark\footnotetext{\footcitetext{key02}}
    %\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `footnote` package can save any footnotes entered inside a float and spit them out at the end (normally they are just thrown away, not sure why).

You only need to add these two lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{figure}
```

You can `\makesavenoteenv` for any other environments you use, like tables.

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. I get the error message `ERROR: Missing } inserted.'

Comment: @user1834164 Without any context it's hard to know what's going wrong. You might consider posting a new question about it on this site.

Answer (score 5):

You can redefine `\footcitetext` as follows:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\footnotetext]
  {\bibsentence%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \global\booltrue{cbx@mlafootnotes}%
   \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:mla:foot}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{mla:foot:postnote}}
```

This is just the `mla`  definition of `\footcite` the only difference is in the optional  argument where we use `\footnotetex` instead of `\mkbibfootnote` as a wrapper for  the citation.

The following MWE

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \caption{A Caption including FootCite \footcite{key01}, note this citation will be omitted from footer. }
    \end{figure}
        \footcitetext{key02}
    The Standard Method (Desired Formatting)\footnotemark\footcitetext{key01}
    The Alternate Method (No Longer Incorrect Formatting)\footcitetext{key02}
\end{document}
```

produces [image]

Comment: Cheers mate....