# Capitalize only first letter in \citet with biblatex and natbib=true

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib, capitalization

I have question concerning the use of the `\citet` command when loading `biblatex` with the option `natbib=true`. I'm a LaTeX beginner and this may be an easy question, but i still couldn't solve it.

I'm writing my thesis in `LaTeX` and i would like to create `in-text` citation call-outs with the command `\citet`. The problem is that in the output the letters of the author all get capitalized. I just want to capitalize the `first letter` of every author.

Is there an option to solve this problem?

```
\RequirePackage{hyphsubst}
\HyphSubstLet{ngerman}{ngerman-x-latest}

\documentclass[final, english, ngerman, a4paper, 12pt, numbers=noenddot, 
cd=true,
cdfont=false,cdfont=nohead,cdfont=nodin,
cdmath=false,
cdhead=false,
cdfoot=true,
cdcover=monochrome,
cdgeometry=asymmetric,
declaration=heading,
declaration=notoc,
abstract=heading,
]{tudscrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{settings/tudbwlimPackages}
\usepackage{settings/tudbwlimStyle}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{svg}

\usepackage{settings/BiblatexSetup}
\AfterPackage*{biblatex}%
{
    \RequirePackage[breaklinks=true, colorlinks=false, linktoc=section, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=black, hidelinks]{hyperref}
    % Da hyperref allerhand Veränderungen an vielen Standardbefehlen vornimmt, sollte dieses als letztes in der Präambel eingebunden werden. Nur Pakete, bei denen in der Dokumentation explizit darauf hingewiesen wird, dass diese nach hyperref zu laden sind, sollten auch danach folgen.
    \hypersetup{pdfprintscaling=None} % gleiches Verhalten, auch ohne hyperref, liefert: \pdfcatalog{/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>}
    \usepackage{footnote} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207192/footcite-in-float-caption
    \makesavenoteenv{figure}
    \makesavenoteenv{table}
    \makesavenoteenv{algorithm}
}
\AfterPackage*{hyperref}
{
    \RequirePackage[automake,acronym,symbols,nomain,translate=babel,]{glossaries}
    \usepackage{settings/GlossariesSetup}
}


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

---

This is the contents of the .sty file

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{ibidtracker=constrict,dashed=false,bibwarn=true,sortlocale=auto,arxiv=false,isbn=true,url=false,doi=false,eprint=false,%
    maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=100,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false,giveninits=true,date=year,ibidtracker=false,%
    % authortitle-dw options
    %namefont=smallcaps,firstnamefont=smallcaps,nopublisher=false,idembib=false,edbyidem=false,addyear=true,journalnumber=afteryear,series=afteryear,safeinputenc=true
}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}

%\DeclareDelimFormat{footcitenametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} %\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\thinspace\&\thinspace}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\thinspace\&\thinspace}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

% authortitle-dw options
%\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\space\slash\space}
%\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\space\slash\space}
%\renewcommand*{\bibrevsdnamedelim}{}
%\renewcommand*{\jourvolstring}{\space Vol.\space}

\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\isdot} %[article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,misc,patent,report,thesis,unpublished]
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % [article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,misc,patent,techreport,thesis,unpublished]
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1},}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}\addnbspace #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}\addnbspace #1}
% authortitle-dw options
%%%\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1},}
%%%\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
%%%\DeclareFieldFormat[masterthesis,misc,article,inproceedings,techreport,phdthesis,mastersthesis,thesis,report,inbook,incollection]{title}{#1.}
%%%\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}


%%\DeclareDelimFormat[cbx@textcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
%%\DeclareDelimFormat[cbx@textcite]{nonameyeardelim}{\addspace}



\newbibmacro*{customfootcite}
{\global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
            {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                \setunit{\addspace}}
            {\printnames{labelname}%
                \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
            \iffieldundef{labelyear}
            {}
            {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}%
                {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}\addcolon\addspace\printtext{\printfield[emph]{title}}}%
                {\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}\addcolon\addspace\printtext{\printfield[emph]{shorttitle}}}%
    }}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{customfootcite}
}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}



% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97376/missing-vol-and-no-in-biblatex-biber
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% was: \setunit*{\addspace}
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}}% was: \setunit{\addspace}
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}, bibliography = {Bibliography}, mathesis = {master's thesis}, phdthesis = {doctoral thesis}, techreport = {technical report}, resreport = {research report}, edition = {edition}, volume = {volume}
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}, bibliography = {Literaturverzeichnis}, mathesis = {Diplomarbeit}, phdthesis = {Dissertation}, techreport = {Technischer Bericht}, resreport = {Forschungsbericht}, edition = {Auflage}, volume = {Band}, jourvol = {Vol.},
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}, bibliography = {Literaturverzeichnis}, mathesis = {Diplomarbeit}, phdthesis = {Dissertation}, techreport = {Technischer Bericht}, resreport = {Forschungsbericht}, edition = {Auflage}, volume = {Band}, jourvol = {Vol.},
}
```

---

The bib entry

```
@Article{Behnamian2015,
  author    = {J. Behnamian},
  title     = {Graph colouring-based algorithm to parallel jobs scheduling on parallel factories},
  journal   = {International Journal of Computer Integrated Manufacturing},
  year      = {2015},
  volume    = {29},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {622--635},
  month     = {oct},
  doi       = {10.1080/0951192x.2015.1099074},
  publisher = {Informa {UK} Limited},
}
```

I hope this one is better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's a bit unclear what you mean, since the standard `biblatex` styles won't do this. Can you edit your question to show a small document that shows what you are doing?  The document should just have `\documentclass{...}\usepackage[....]{biblatex}\begin{document}\citet{...}\printbibliography\end{document}` along with an example `.bib` file entry that shows the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...One of an old package may help you, i.e., `inicap.sty` which was developed by `Michael J Downes`

Comment: @MadyYuvi Given how unclear the question is at the moment, and the fact that this is a `biblatex` question, it's unlikely that a package that isn't even in TeX Live will solve the problem.

Comment: Presumably, you're loading the `biblatex` package with several options. So far, you've told us that one of the options is `natbib=true`. What are the other options?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers. With the \citet{behnamian} command i get the output ---> BEHNAMIAN (2014) . But i would like to get the output --> Behnamian (2014). Thank you in advance

Comment: i edit the options in the post above. @AlanMunn i´ll try to

Comment: Can  you also add to your question the actual `.bib` entry for your "Behnamian" citation.

Comment: @MadyYuvi what do i have to do? i don´t quite know how to change it.

Comment: Thanks for adding these bits. When I turn the fragments you've given into a complete document I don't get an upper case citation callout, so there must be something else you're not showing us.

Comment: @AlanMunn Agreed....

Comment: Sorry. I really want to give all the informations. but I´m not sure what is needed. The document is based on a biblatex design file. I show a part of it above

Comment: @masc3265 Do you listout all the `\usepackage{...}` tags in your post?

Comment: If you look at my first comment, the idea is that you need to be able to show a minimal document that exhibits the problem you're having. If you make a minimal document with the pieces you've given, the citation callout is not capitalized. But until you can show us how you got that output, it will be hard to help you.  Please don't post fragments of code. Put them together so that people can see exactly what you are doing. What "style file" are you referring to? This is clearly the source of the problem, but we don't know what it is.

Comment: sorry. i edit the post.

Comment: Ok, it's getting warmer. Please tell us what's in the file `BiblatexSetup.sty`.

Comment: I posted this quite fast. hope i didn´t forget anything. And i´ll copy with the styles in this forum, sorry for that. I´m really thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are loading a private package `\usepackage{settings/BiblatexSetup}` which is changing the way `biblatex` is working. This line from that package:

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

is what is what is causing names to show up in small caps (`\textsc`).  Do you know *why* you're loading this package? Is it required by your university? If so, then perhaps the small caps names are a requirement. If you don't know why you're loading the package, you may not want to load it at all.  If you only need to change this one thing, and everything else that the package does meets your specifications, you can add the following line to your preamble after loading the package:

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You guys are great. I thought the template is all I need, so I used, but it didn´t work for me in this case. This is not a requirement, but since there aren´t plenty templates I took this one and modified it.

Comment: I have one last question. Is it possible to change the citation format for one or two cites back to capital letters ? That would be a requirement for some cites. If i write it without command in text the entry won´t show up in the 
bibliography, am i right?

Comment: As a quick fix you could define a simple `\sccitet` command like this: `\newcommand{\sccitet}[1]{\textsc{\citeauthor{#1}}~(\citeyear{#1})}` and use `\sccitet{...}` when you want an upper case callout. To do it properly though (i.e., to allow pre- and post-notes) and work correctly with the *ibid* tracker, you'd need to do a lot more work.

Comment: A quick fix should work for that, since the ibid tracker won´t be necessary. This works fine for me. I just need to include the page number like in citet[]{}. How do i do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ah sorry. i realized that this one is the postnote

Comment: May I suggest `\newcommand*{\sctextcite}{\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}}\textcite}` instead of combining `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` in one command?

Comment: @moewe Yes you may! I forgot about `\AtNextCite`, and I thought that it would require a whole new cite command.

Comment: @masc3265 You should use the command suggested by moewe.

Comment: It's a neat little trick used in `blx-natbib.def` to define the `natbib` compatibility names. I can never remember what the command is called, but if you know where to copy-and-paste stuff from ...